# removing google maps object from div

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created a map in div tag.later on at some user action I want to create the map of another station and draw new markers on it. How should I clear the map object in same div tag?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <title>Google Maps Markers</title> <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 650px; height: 250px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">


var map;

var DFWCenter =  new google.maps.LatLng(32.9017,-97.0405770);    

function showMap()
  {

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 15,
    center: DFWCenter,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID  
    });

 }
```

If I do map=null, it still does not clear the map from div tag.

Answer (score 1):

Don't destroy the existing map, re-use it.  Call `map.setCenter()` and `map.setZoom()` with the new place (or `map.fitBounds()` with the new desired bounds).  Remove all the existing markers and create new ones.

(note: there have been reports of memory leaks when attempting to destroy a map instance and recreate it, see [issue 3803 on the issues list](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3803), there may be others)

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip .. But I am creating this map from flex and I need to destroy the map before creating a new one. How to destroy the map in javascript api? is it just map=null?